# How to get rid of the buzzing sound in speakers in a Bluetooth + battery + inverter portable setup?

Tags: batteries, ground, inverter, speakers

I setup a bike trailer speaker system.

There are two JBL EON610s (these are powered speakers with a built in amplifier,) one Bestek Pure Sine Wave 500W inverter, one 60Ah lithium battery, and one Esinkin Bluetooth receiver (this receives music signal from my phone and outputs 1/4 inch left and right to each speaker.)

I thought that the buzzing sound would be fixed by using a pure sine inverter but this did not solve it.

Any ideas on how to fix this sort of buzzing sound?

[image]

New finding: The bluetooth receiver and the inverter don't work well together. - The speakers work fine (no noise) with the battery powered bluetooth receiver when the power comes from the wall. - The speakers work fine (no noise) with the USB DAC when the power comes from the inverter + battery. They just don't work together..

Comment: Identify the problem, and fix it. You have the equipment so you can fault find. We don't, which makes it more difficult. Start by removing the signal source and see if the amps buzz on their own; and does the buzz depend on volume setting?

Comment: `Pure Sine Wave` is a brand name, not a technical specification

Comment: Are your cables from the bluetooth receiver to the amplified speakers shielded audio cables? I doubt they are huge 1/4 inch. Does the battery or inverter power a motor or something else?

Comment: not shielded audio cables, perhaps they should be?

Just powering the speakers

Comment: @user_1818839 'Identify the problem, and fix it' ... you should put this for all stack exchange questions, it's super helpful.

Comment: New finding:
The bluetooth receiver and the inverter don't work well together.
- The speakers work fine (no noise) with the battery powered bluetooth receiver when the power comes from the wall.
- The speakers work fine (no noise) with the USB DAC when the power comes from the inverter + battery.
They just don't work together...    So I don't know

Comment: The sound might be because of the inverter,what kind of inverter are you using is it a square wave or a pure sine wave.perhaps you could try shielding the inverter because the electromagnetic radiation from the inverter might cause the problem

Comment: @KylePennell I sometimes do. You need a certain mindset for faultfinding, grasshopper.(Please ... don't trickle out relevant info in comments : edit the question). Now you have localised the problem : that's progress. If the bluetooth RX is separately powered (from its own battery) does it still buzz? If you move it away from the inverter, does it buzz less?

Comment: [Amazon](https://www.amazon.com/JBL-EON610-Multipurpose-Self-Powered-Reinforcement/dp/B00P7XRV98) and [JBL](https://jblpro.com/products/eon610) say that the EON610 has Bluetooth built in.  Is there a reason not to use it,or do you have a different model?

Comment: @JRE - I really wish that were the case... 'Bluetooth pairing with the EON600 speakers lets you remote control the volume and EQ parameters'

It doesn't let you send music in, just mess with the EQ a bit.